# How to check the result of status's within a loop after it completes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a loop that creates refunds for any purchase under an order.

An order can have multiple payments on it (if user upgrades shipping, adds items to cart after initial payment and resubmits, etc.)  This isn't conventonial for ecommerce but it's needed in this case.

I have this loop:

```
orders_payments = Payment.where()
  orders_payments.each do |btp|
    transaction = gateway.transaction.find("#{btp.transaction_token}")
    if transaction.status == "submitted_for_settlement"
      void = gateway.transaction.void("#{btp.transaction_token}")
      if void.success?
        format.html { redirect_to user_orders_path, notice: 'Order refund was successfully refunded.' }
      else
        format.html { redirect user_orders_path, notice: 'Order refund unsuccessful.' }
      end
    elsif transaction.status == "settled"
      refund = gateway.transaction.refund("#{btp.transaction_token}")
      if refund.success?
         format.html { redirect_to user_orders_path, notice: 'Order refund was successfully refunded.' }
      else
         format.html { redirect user_orders_path, notice: 'Order refund unsuccessful.' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Of course, this doesn't work due to the redirects.  But aside from not creating a redirect... and it's important I have a redirect with a message of the status... How can I check the status of the voids or refunds AFTER the loop is created.

I would like to be able to check which ones worked and which ones didn't work.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: The easiest is to define a variable outside the loop and save the status of each iteration inside that variable and use it after the loop.

Comment: Why not `map` the payments into a different structure, then use that to determine the outcome? If this is Rails this is something you can push into the `Payment` model so it can give you a simple status result for what is an otherwise complex query.

Comment: @arieljuod I'm confused on what you mean.  are you saying to  create a variable, instead of `void` or `refund`, do something like `void-<%= btp.id %>`? if so or not, actually very confused, sorry

Comment: @tadman can you show a simple example to get me to understand what you're aiming at? Are you saying to simply just use `map` instead of `each`?  As for the status of the payment, this is something you get back from BrainTree only after you attempt a refund/void...there isn't a webhook for this, from my readings of their docs

Comment: Is all of this in a controller action? I would look at extracting transaction, void, refund, etc into their own models/controllers/services. Each of them will most likely come with a bunch of complexity that should be handled separately.

Comment: Note: `"#{x}"` should often be just `x`, the quotes do nothing useful.

Comment: Max has a good demonstration of the principle in their answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than do a single loop, you can use multiple loops to split up your data into categories.

The first step in your iteration is to retrieve the `transaction` object. This can also be done with [`map`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map):

```
transactions = orders_payments.map do |btp|
  gateway.transaction.find("#{btp.transaction_token}")
end
```

The next step is the `if` statement that splits the data into 2 groups according to their status. You can do use [`select`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/select) to construct these 2 lists:

```
submitted = transactions.select do |transaction|
  transaction.status == "submitted_for_settlement"
end
settled = transactions.select do |transaction|
  transaction.status == "settled"
end
```

The next step is to process both of the lists and track which ones succeeded or failed. It sounds like at the end of this you want a "successful" and "failure" list for each of the transaction groups, leaving you with 4 lists. [`partition`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/partition) is a good method for this use-case:

```
successful_submitted, failed_submitted = submitted.partition do |transaction|
  gateway.transaction.void("#{btp.transaction_token}").success?
end
successful_settled, failed_settled = settled.partition do |transaction|
  gateway.transaction.refund("#{btp.transaction_token}").success?
end
```

Comment: Note that this pulls all of `orders_payments` and `transactions` into memory. If there are many that could consume a lot of memory. Use `find_each.collect` instead to at least void pulling all of `orders_payments` into memory. `transactions = orders_payments.find_each.collect { |btp| ... }`

Comment: I tried this out and a handful of ways but couldn't get this to work somehow.  I'm sure I am doing something completely wrong in my attempt.  I ended up being able to have multiple notices by using a blank array and storing the array with flash.keep and then redirecting after the loop with all of the messages within.  It's ugly but works for now.  I will come back to this and refactor once I am complete with the app.  I appreciate your time and am grateful for your responses

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to store the statuses. Here I'm storing them in a Hash by `transaction_token`.

Note that I'm using [`find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) rather than `each` to avoid pulling all the records into memory at once.

```
transaction_statuses = orders_payments.find_each.each_with_object({}) do |btp,status|
  transaction = gateway.transaction.find("#{btp.transaction_token}")
  status[btp.transaction_token] = case
  when transaction.status == "submitted_for_settlement"
    { voided: gateway.transaction.void("#{btp.transaction_token}") }
  when transaction.status == "settled"
    { refunded: gateway.transaction.refund("#{btp.transaction_token}") }
  end
end
```

And then do something later with them.

```
transaction_statuses.each do |token,status|
  case
  when status[:voided]
    case
    when status[:voided].success?
      puts "Order #{token} was successfully voided."
    else
      puts "Order #{token} void failed."
    end
  when status[:refunded]
    case
    when status[:refunded].success?
      puts "Order #{token} was successfully refunded."
    else
      puts "Order #{token} refund failed."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: one small fix, I think you would get an error for `status[btp.transaction_token][:voided] =` unless you declared `status[btp.transaction_token]` to a hash or use the constructor for a hash with default values

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming here because you are having the same or similar issue, before reading this, I suggest reading max pleaner's and Schwern's answers on this question.

The following works but may be a very beginner way I doing what I wanted to do.

I create a blank array, and then store the messages in it with `flash.keep` and then redirect after the loop completes with all messages, whether successful or declined refunds.

```
orders_payments = Payment.where()
messages = []
  orders_payments.each do |btp|
    transaction = gateway.transaction.find("#{btp.transaction_token}")
    if transaction.status == "submitted_for_settlement"
      void = gateway.transaction.void("#{btp.transaction_token}")
      if void.success?
         messages << "Refund Successful message"
      else
         messages << "Refund unSuccessful message"
      end
    elsif transaction.status == "settled"
      refund = gateway.transaction.refund("#{btp.transaction_token}")
      if refund.success?
         messages << "Refund successful message"
      else
         messages << "Refund unSuccessful message"
      end
    end
  end
  flash.keep[:notice] = messages.join if messages.any?
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to route }
  end
  ...
```